# Is my IDisposable implemented correctly in my class or needs some changes

Tags: c#, idisposable

I have got below code in C# 2.0 and I am trying to implement IDisposable in my class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Xml.Xsl;
using Tridion.ContentManager;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Templating;
using Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement;
using Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Fields;
using Emirates.Tridion.BuildingBlocks.Base;
using th = my.Tridion.BuildingBlocks.Base.TemplateHelper;
using ut = my.Tridion.BuildingBlocks.Base.Utilities;
using tc = Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement;
using System.IO;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

namespace my.BuildingBlocks.Utilities
{

    [TcmTemplateTitle("Page Metadata Values")]
    public class PageMetaDataValues : TemplateBase, IDisposable
    {

        private bool m_Disposed = false;

        protected bool Disposed
        {
            get
            {
                lock (this)
                {
                    return (m_Disposed);
                }
            }
        }


        public override void Transform(Engine engine, Package package)
        {
            Initialize(engine, package);
            m_Logger.Info("Start of Page Metadata Values");
            tc.Publication pubObject= m_Engine.GetSession().GetObject(m_Publication.Id) as tc.Publication;          
            if (pubObject != null)
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(ut.RenderPageLocale(pubObject));
            }
            package.PushItem("PageMetaDataValues", package.CreateStringItem(ContentType.Xml, RenderCurrentPageXML()));
            m_Logger.Info("End of Page Metadata Values");
        }

        private string RenderCurrentPageXML()
        {
            m_Logger.Info("Rendering the Page Metadata Values");

            XmlDocument pageDoc = new XmlDocument();
            pageDoc.LoadXml(GetCurrentPageXML(m_Page.Id));
            return pageDoc.InnerXml;
        }      

        void IDisposable.Dispose
        {   
            get
            {
                lock (this)
                {
                    if (m_Disposed == false)
                    {
                        Cleanup();
                        m_Disposed = true;
                        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        protected virtual void Cleanup()
        {
            /* do cleanup of unmanaged resources here */
        }
        #endregion

    }
}
```

Please suggest whether I have implemnted IDisposable interface correclty or I need to do some code changes above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the normal [IDisposable pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163392.aspx), typically you'd do something more like:

```
public class DisposableClass : IDisposable
{
    ~DisposableClass()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    private bool disposed = false;
    protected bool Disposed
    {
        get
        {
            return (disposed);
        }
    }

    public override void Transform(Engine engine, Package package)
    {
        if( Disposed )
        {
             throw new ObjectDisposedException();
        }

        Initialize(engine, package);
        m_Logger.Info("Start of Page Metadata Values");
        tc.Publication pubObject= m_Engine.GetSession().GetObject(m_Publication.Id) as tc.Publication;          
        if (pubObject != null)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(ut.RenderPageLocale(pubObject));
        }
        package.PushItem("PageMetaDataValues", package.CreateStringItem(ContentType.Xml, RenderCurrentPageXML()));
        m_Logger.Info("End of Page Metadata Values");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            disposed = true;
            // Clean up all managed resources
        }

        // Clean up all native resources
    }
}
```

Comment: So you suggest to go with this approach, ok then how that method needs to be written where this is mentioned // TODO: Call the appropriate methods to clean up unmanaged resources here

Comment: @Manu that all depends on what unmanaged resources you have around; for the managed resources, is typically where you'd call `Dispose` on them

Comment: btw part of the Disposable specification is that you should be able to call Dispose multiple times without any ill-effect, so it's usually a good idea to check for this.disposed in the Dispose method first

Comment: Can I ask you why you are locking on read `Disposed` but not on write?  As written there is no guarantee the `disposed = true` will ever be really written somewhere in memory (the write could be delayed indefinitely)

Comment: @xanatos Because I copy and pasted the original poster's code for that. oops.

Comment: @RowlandShaw The original `IDisposable.Dispose` (that was a property used as a method) had a good `lock (this)`.

Comment: I'll add that, as written, the `lock` is quite useless: you could call a method on Thread 1, it locks, checks the disposes state, unlocks and executes. Meanwhile (during the executes part) thread 2 disposes: the lock is in "untaken" state so thread 2 takes it, disposes everything and unlock. But thread 1 is still executing on an object in disposes state.

Comment: I'll add that a "correct" solution that supports multiple threads and "protects" against Dispose from other threads is through the use of a class-wide (a member) `ReaderWriterLockSlim`. Each method/property enter in Read mode when it begins and check for Disposed (no lock or volatile needed) and exits the Read Mode when it exits. The Dispose enters in Write mode when it begins, checks and sets the Disposed (no lock or volatile needed) and exits the Write mode when it has finished disposing. In this way the Dispose won't execute while there are threads running other methods.

Comment: A simpler approach is to make m_Disposed be an "int", and use Interlocked.Exchange to set it.  Complex classes shouldn't override Finalize() for any purpose other than--possibly--logging failures to dispose; anything else a class should want to do in a finalizer should be done within a lightweight class whose purpose is to ensure the necessary cleanup gets done.  The only way to enter Dispose(bool) should be via the non-virtual Dispose() method, which should use Interlocked.Exchange to ensure it's called only once.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a finializer that calls Cleanup to. In case someone don't call Dispose as they should, the unmanaged resources will then eventually be cleaned up by the garbage collector.

That's why you are calling `GC.SuppressFinalize(this);` in the first place, to make sure that the GC does not call your finalizer if the object was disposed properly.

**EDIT**

That means that you at least need to add:

```
public ~PageMetaDataValues(){
  Cleanup();
}
```

There are however some other strange cases in your code like locking on `this` and so on. Also, are you expecting to dispose the same object from several different threads since you added the locking in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
    void IDisposable.Dispose
    {   
        get
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                if (m_Disposed == false)
                {
                    Cleanup();
                    m_Disposed = true;
                    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

to

```
    public void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {   
            lock (this)
            {
                if (m_Disposed == false)
                {
                    Cleanup();
                    m_Disposed = true;
                    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As written by others (the ControlPower solution is correct), the Dispose method is a method, not a property :-).

Now we will look at another problem: you are trying to implement a thread safe `IDisposable` pattern. To do it correctly is quite complex. Let's see the naive solution. Yours (with the corrections of Controlpower) is ok :-) Clearly you should check the `Disposed` property at the beginning of each public method/property and if it's true, you should throw an `ObjectDisposedException`. A better (faster) implementation is the one given by http://blogs.msdn.com/b/blambert/archive/2009/07/24/a-simple-and-totally-thread-safe-implementation-of-idisposable.aspx

he uses `Interlocked.CompareExchange` instead of `lock`. It's faster.

It still suffers from one problem: if Thread A executes method A1 and at the same time Thread B executes a `Dispose` of the object, Thread A could be mid-method when the object is disposed. I'll give you a third solution. It used `ReaderWriterLockSlim`. Every public method/property takes a reader lock when it executes. Dispose takes a write lock when it executes. Many "normal" methods can be executed at the same time. Dispose needs to be executed when no one else is executing. Private and protected methods/properties (that aren't part of an interface) don't need to check for the disposed state because they are called from public methods/properties.

```
class MyClass : IDisposable
{
    protected ReaderWriterLockSlim disposeLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim(LockRecursionPolicy.SupportsRecursion);
    protected bool isDisposed = false; 

    ~MyClass()
    {
        this.Dispose(false);
    }

    public int ExamplePublicProperty
    {
        get
        {
            disposeLock.EnterReadLock();

            try
            {
                if (isDisposed)
                {
                    throw new ObjectDisposedException(GetType().FullName);
                }

                // The property

                return 0; // What you want to return
            }
            finally
            {
                disposeLock.ExitReadLock();
            }
        }

        set
        {
            disposeLock.EnterReadLock();

            try
            {
                if (isDisposed)
                {
                    throw new ObjectDisposedException(GetType().FullName);
                }

                // The property
            }
            finally
            {
                disposeLock.ExitReadLock();
            }
        }
    }

    // The same for private methods
    protected int ExampleProtectedProperty
    {
        // Here we don't need to check for isDisposed
        get;
        set;
    }

    public void ExamplePublicMethod()
    {
        disposeLock.EnterReadLock();

        try
        {
            if (isDisposed)
            {
                throw new ObjectDisposedException(GetType().FullName);
            }

            // The method
        }
        finally
        {
            disposeLock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }

    // The same for private methods
    protected void ExampleProtectedMethod()
    {
        // Here we don't need to check for isDisposed
    }

    #region IDisposable Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        disposeLock.EnterWriteLock();

        try
        {
            if (isDisposed)
            {
                return;
            }

            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);

            isDisposed = true;
        }
        finally
        {
            disposeLock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }

    #endregion

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        // do the freeing
    }
}
```